# Python (QtDesigner) Opening multiple .py files in MdiArea window with buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I used QtDesigner to create all of my windows, the main window uses mdiArea so that other windows fit inside of it when called. My main problem is when I close a window inside the mdiArea it disappears and I can't reopen it, id either like the window to not have a exit button or make a window with buttons that will open the files if its not there.

Output Screenshot

[image]

The window that is minimized is ValveSimulator and if I close it it doesn't exist anymore and I can't open it

my main code: CreateWindow makes the window with the buttons and CreateValveSimulator is my main program that I want to open from the button when I close it

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget,QWidget, QMdiSubWindow
import ValveSim
import MainWindow
import Window

class Win1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.vtn = MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.vtn.setupUi(self)
        self.subwindow = QMdiSubWindow()
        self.CreateValveSimulator()
        self.CreateWindow()

    def CreateValveSimulator(self):
        widget = QMainWindow()
        self.VSim_subwindow = ValveSim.Ui_ValveSim()
        self.VSim_subwindow.setupUi(widget)
        self.subwindow = QMdiSubWindow(self.vtn.mdiArea)
        widget.setParent(self.subwindow)
        self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)
        self.vtn.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
        widget.show()
        self.subwindow.show()
        self.subwindow.widget().show()

    def CreateWindow(self):
        widget = QMainWindow()
        self.win_subwindow = Window.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.win_subwindow.setupUi(widget)
        self.subwindow = QMdiSubWindow(self.vtn.mdiArea)
        widget.setParent(self.subwindow)
        self.subwindow.setWidget(widget)
        self.vtn.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
        widget.show()
        self.subwindow.show()
        self.subwindow.widget().show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Win1()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I connected the self.pushbutton to a function called openvs which I hope to open the Valve Simulator window when its closed as shown in my main code,however it just crashes when I click the button

Table with buttons code:

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QWidget, QMdiSubWindow, QAction
import Untitled
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        MainWindow.resize(351, 442)
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(85, 125, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(85, 195, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 125, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openvs)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Valve Simulator"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Module Program"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Metal Sizing"))

    def openvs(self):
        Untitled.Win1.CreateValveSimulator()
```

Comment: Could you share all your code through github, drive or similar?

Comment: what is ValveSim?

Comment: The main code that is run is the the code with Class Win1(). MainWindow is the GUI made with mdiArea in QtDesigner, and ValveSim and Window are just regular GUI made from QtDesigner that will go inside the MainWindow(mdiArea).. Window is the GUI with buttons that will open up a new ValveSim window when it is closed as shown on screenshot...Win1 combines both regular GUI inside the MainWindow

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzcHlfStubD3a281dEtOTWRsNFk?usp=sharing

Comment: What I understand is that you want to open ValveSim using the "Open Valve simulator" button, am I correct?

Comment: I have made some modifications, please verify that that is what you want. The code is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/TestMdiArea)

Comment: Yes, thank you! One issue though, when you minimize the Valve Simulator then close it while it is minimized and you press the Open Valve Simulator it doesn't open

Comment: Update my code, check if it's what you want, I'll publish my answer right now

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create the windows independently, and add them to each QMdiSubWindow. When the widget is displayed in the subwindow this will cause the subwindow to be displayed. To open normally with the button you must use the clicked signal and call the showNormal function.

*The complete code is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/TestMdiArea).*

```
class HomeWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_HomeWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class ValveSim(QMainWindow, Ui_ValveSim):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Win1(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.vs = ValveSim()
        self.hw = HomeWindow()
        self.CreateValveSimulator()
        self.CreateWindow()

    def CreateValveSimulator(self):
        subwindow = QMdiSubWindow()
        subwindow.setWidget(self.vs)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subwindow)
        subwindow.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        # self.subwindow.close()

    def CreateWindow(self):
        self.hw.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.vs.showNormal)
        subwindow = QMdiSubWindow()
        subwindow.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.Tool)
        subwindow.setWidget(self.hw)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subwindow)
```

Comment: Thank you, next thing that is almost similar to this is I created a settings window in QtDesigner, and I want when I click the File->Settings->Working Directory (This button is on MainWindow) to have this window pop up